# Border around content in container created with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a div with content inside that is pulled using the ng-repeat and am trying to put a border and all around it. The content could stretch 1, 4, or even 10 items as shown in image below. Is this even possible with using ng-repeat and if so, how? My code that generates this is:

```
    <div class="claimedTable" style="background-color: yellow;">
        <div ng-repeat="item in claimsSubmit" style="background-color: yellow; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.5); border-radius: 2px;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0;">
                <span>service date:</span>
                <span style="float: right; padding-right: 15px;">{{ item.fromDate }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0;">
                <span>provider:</span>
                <span style="margin-left: 60%;">{{ item.provider }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0;">
                <span>amount:</span>
                <span style="margin-left: 60%;">{{ item.amount }}</span>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
```

What this currently produces is (notice the thick line at top, that is my border and such):

[image]

Actually, if I revise now and my code looks like (previously the background color was just checking what was being rendered in the view):

```
    <div class="claimedTable" style="min-height: 400px; box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.5); border-radius: 2px;">
        <div ng-repeat="item in claimsSubmit">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0; padding-top: 25px;">
                <span>service date:</span>
                <span style="float: right; padding-right: 15px;">{{ item.fromDate }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0;">
                <span>provider:</span>
                <span style="margin-left: 60%;">{{ item.provider }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0;">
                <span>amount:</span>
                <span style="margin-left: 60%;">{{ item.amount }}</span>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I get this image to start because I specified a min-height:

[image]

But as I enter data and it exceeds, I get this over run as shown:

[image]

It seems that since I only specified a "minimum", that the border would grow. Why is this not true?

Comment: how about just doing border: 1px solid #MYCOLOR  -  and omitting the border-width

Comment: I think this is not true because, css is applied first and then the DOM gets bigger... I think you should apply the min-width with javascript by checking how many elements are repeated

Comment: But since this is being done in angular and it does not actually refresh, how would I apply a min-height variable since the repeat is simply adding to the dom rather than re-rendering the dom?

Comment: Can you post your additional CSS code? The code you posted here seems to work fine (safari / firefox on a mac)

http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/wbkv98hu/1/

Comment: The idea was the wrapper would cover the entire thing. In this case, as you have shown, it does it individual which ultimately, I decided to go that route.